# Remove validation error message from Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

Fairly simple question here.

I put a validation in my icon model `validates_presence_of :icon`.

When I try to upload an empty icon, a red message "can't be blank" automatically shows up in my view.

The problem is that I am outputting these messages on my own using the standard block:

```
<% if @icon.errors.any? %>
  <% @icon.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I don't want both of the error messages to show up. How do I eliminate the automatically generated error message?

EDIT: Here is my new.html.erb file where the message is being rendered.

```
<h1>New Icon</h1>
<%= form_for @icon do |f| %>
  <% if @icon.errors.any? %>
    <% @icon.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <%= msg %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :icon %>
  <%= f.file_field :icon %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

There is only one `msg` being printed, but the view is showing the message printed twice.

Comment: is there any code or partials for rendering errors in the layout?

Comment: no, none at all. Which is why I'm stuck. I'm including my entire new.html.erb file for my model.

Comment: where is the code for your custom messages?

Comment: The messages themselves aren't custom, I'm simply using the errors that are generated by the validation.

Comment: have you inspected the errors object to see how many errors are in it?

Comment: Yeah, in my case there is definitely only one object in errors. If I take out that entire error block from my view, one error message is still being rendered.

Comment: there has to be some code somewhere else that is also rendering it.

Comment: Is it possible that the other is a 'flash' message that you are setting in the controller?

Comment: @Aaron, you're right but I've also checked my application views and there is nothing. @RajeshKolappakam my controller code is just `@icon = Icon.new` for the new action.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a wild guess, but i assume, that you somehow managed to validate the same thing twice. rails is not really clever about his validations, so putting this in your model:

```
validates_presence_of :icon
validates_presence_of :icon
```

will generate 2 identical error messages

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've done some more investigation and determined the issue actually lies with Twitter Bootstrap, which provides some bootstrap flash javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to override that for one view